# When using set record in plpgsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an issue with records in plpgsql.

I tried to return a set of record like this. But postgres doesn't want it and raise me en error so how can I do that ?

Error is something like I cannot return a set in a context who don't accept sets

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION project.getQuestionsTag(VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    name_tag ALIAS FOR $1;
    question RECORD;
    exit RECORD;
begin
    FOR question IN
     SELECT qu.id_question, qu.title,
     FROM project.questions qu, project.question_tags qt, project.tags ta
     WHERE qu.id_question = qt.id_question AND qt.name = ta.name
     AND ta.name = name_tag loop
         SELECT question.id_question, question.title INTO exit;
         RETURN NEXT exit;
     end loop;
         RETURN;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: what is the error, you are getting

Comment: Error is something like I cannot return a set in a context who don't accept sets

Comment: can you share how do you call  function and the error exactly ? maybe the error code inclusive, please